# How to make a lookup query to another table filter out records based on existing relationships between tables without macros?

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: relationships]

Given those relationships, how do I limit the choice of Leader in a given record in GroupResults to only those StudentResults.IDs, which have Class&Group set to the same value as in the ID field of that record without creating forms and using VBA?

If I assign `SELECT StudentResults.ID, StudentResults.FullName FROM StudentResults;` to the Row Source in [Leader], like this [image: table design],
I get all the records in the table to choose from, regardless of the [Class&Group] field value, like this [image: undesired results].
How do I restrict the assignable records to only those that belong to the corresponding group?

I'd spent a very long time trying to find a way to run a parametrised SQL query to pass the [Class&Group] to the WHERE clause, but eventually had to give up.

Thank you very much for your help!

P.S. I do realise that this may or may not be more of an ms-access, rather than SQL question.

Comment: Please post attempted query and undesired results. This is a relatively straightforward `JOIN` unless I am missing something: `SELECT g.Leader FROM GroupResults g INNER JOIN StudentResults s ON g.ID = s.[Class&Group]`

Comment: I guess I wasn't specific enough - the SQL query is for the lookup implemented in the Leader field to choose one of the students in the StudentResults table, but rather than it offering the entire StudentResults table to choose from I need it to only allow selecting a record with the matching Class&Group value.

Comment: Rather than tell us please show us with specific actual data. I still am not sure of your desired result or overall needs.

Comment: I've edited the post to make it easier to take it from there.

Comment: Ahh! You want to set up a lookup combobox on a table field. You cannot set such conditional logic as you would need a form.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid - hence the idea of somehow passing the condition parameters to the SQL string in the Row Source (I'm totally new to DB). I do know how to do it with forms though (not new to VB). Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are not designed to be user interfaces. Conditional comboboxes, validation, etc. work best on forms. Comboxbox lookup dropdowns are more an Access GUI convenience to show parent table indicators for key number values.

When queries are then run from such tables, these drop downs fields show to help us humans who naturally understand names and indicators rather than integer primary/foreign keys. So instead of *Student:  1*, we see *Student: John Doe*. In fact, such table field drop downs even helps generate the same comboboxes on Access forms and reports in advance to avoid the designer in building them upon clicking the form icons on ribbon.

However, for your needs consider adjusting combobox by showing the *[Class&Group]* field so the user can see or match the group of specific *Leader* with appropriate one for current record in *Class* column. See adjusted query and column count/heads.

```
Row Source: SELECT s.ID, s.[Class&Group], s.FullName FROM StudentResults s                       
Bound Column: 1
Column Count: 3
Column Heads: Yes
```

Also, if you want the *Leader* name to always show when table or query is opened instead of ID, reverse the order in query and change bound column:

```
Row Source: SELECT s.FullName, s.[Class&Group], s.ID FROM StudentResults
Bound Column: 3
Column Count: 3
Column Heads: Yes
```